# Why is my system experiencing high CPU usage on restart?

Tags: high-cpu-usage

I've noticed recently that after every restart my PC — a new PC build, maybe 8 weeks old — is at 15% CPU usage when idling instead of the usual 1-2%. Nothing else is running at the time.  I'm not sure when this started as I only started paying attention to the CPU usage recently.

Key observations:

- It seems to only happen when the PC has been running and a restart / shut down is done thereafter and it boots up again.
- This does not happen if the PC has been switched off for a few minutes and started up again.
- It also seems to go away when the PC has been in sleep mode for a couple of hours regardless if the issue was present or not beforehand.

When this happens I can hear the CPU fan is louder than usual, and I can hear this happening even before Windows starts up.

CPU usage for core 0 is at 100% constantly when this happens. Task manager displays usage as SYSTEM at 10% CPU usage which is high.

Other symptoms:

- Not sure if this is normal but I always thought that when a restart is done that everything powers off. Including all fans and all lights and then powers back on again. It used to be this way but it recently changed. Now the case fans and RGB lights keep running and don't power off. I can see that the motherboard resets itself as the onboard LEDs go off / on and change color. Screen, mouse, and keyboard go off and on again like usual and Windows resets as usual, just not sure if it should be this way or not.
- CPU fan RGB lights used to go off when fiddling with fan speeds. And would either stay off or only come on again when logging into Windows. Usually, it would be on at startup. This is solved by simply unplugging the fan RGB cable, doing a power cycle and plugging it back in. Not sure if it's related to any of this.

My setup:

- Windows 10
- Asus ROG B460 - H Motherboard
- I5 10400F CPU
- Nvidia 1650 S GPU
- Corsair Vengeance DDR4 1X16GB 3200MHZ Ram
- Adata XPG SX8200 Pro-NVME 256G SSD for Windows
- WD Blue SSD 500GB
- WD 1TB HDD
- Gamdias Helios E1 500W PSU

Things I have tried:

- BIOS update / revert to previous versions - no effect
- Clean startup - no effect
- Disabled non-essential apps at startup - no effect
- Uninstalled recent apps / games - no effect
- Updated drivers on all hardware - no effect
- Updated all software to latest version - no effect
- Reset virtual memory - no effect
- All Windows updates up to date - no effect
- Many different BIOS settings like disabling turbo / performance mode / power settings / rapid start - no effect
- Power settings in Windows - no effect
- Ruled out CMOS battery issues
- Disable fast startup - no effect
- Scanned for malware - no effect
- Run DISM health scans and other commands - no effect
- Reinstall Windows - no effect

Things I did that seemed to have solved it temporarily:

- Disabled onboard LAN controller in BIOS - pc did a full shut down thereafter and started up normally, the problem was solved until I did a restart.

I ran WPA and found the ntoskrnl.exe and ACPI.sys was causing the high CPU usage but I have no idea how to proceed from here. Two things that caught my attention was ntoskrnl.exe!PspSystemThreadStartup and ACPI.sys!RestartCtxtPassive, since my issue is being caused at startup or restart. I don't know what to make of this.

Could anyone please give me some advice on how to proceed from here? I'm stumped.

[image]

Comment: Could you ease back on the CAPSLOCK usage. It just makes it look shouty & harder to read.

Comment: The operating system may be checking for all manner of updates and doing a startup Anti Virus scan.  If CPU percent drops to normal in 15 minutes, then likely nothing to worry about.

Comment: It never drops back to where it should, it remains like that all the time as long as it's powered on.

Comment: This is not normal and you have reinstalled Windows so I would continue checking the hardware.

Comment: I'm also leaning towards hardware as I'm running out of options. What do you think it most likely would be? PSU or motherboard? And aside from swopping out components (which I don't have) how do I actually test to see if it's faulty?

Comment: It is hard to know. If you can check the Power Supply voltage outputs and if they are within tolerance, then I would lean toward the motherboard. If out of tolerance by more than 3% then it may be the PSU.

Comment: I did cheap out on the PSU with this build. One thing I forgot to mention - if you flip the switch on the back of the PSU to the on position the motherboard led turns on. If you proceed to hit the power button on the case the fans start spinning, the lights come on but keyboard and screen remain off, It then shuts down and starts up by itself normally after that. I didn't know if this was some kind of feature or if it's abnormal since everything was working fine after that so I didn't pay much attention to it. Does this sound normal to you?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but the PSU should not operate like that - at least I do not think so. It may be time to try a better quality power supply - one that is overated for the job in terms of load capacity and one that has accurate and stable output voltages for all normal loads (good regulation).

Comment: "Not sure if this is normal but I always thought that when a restart is done that everything powers off. " - What you describe is a shutdown.  Restarting your machine shouldn't result in your machine turning off.  There is a reason a start is often called a "soft boot"

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, I was unsure about this and couldn't find a straight answer on Google, surprisingly. But in the early weeks after finishing this build the power did cut off entirely whenever I did a restart, it's no longer doing that though, which was confusing to me.

Comment: Thank you John, I will certainly buy a better PSU somewhere in the near future and hopefully that fixes it. I just really hope that is the problem instead of something else since it's such an easy fix.

Comment: It doesn't sound like anything is actually broken to me.  How often do you reboot?  Those CPU cycles are going SOMEWHERE.. if it bugged you enough, your would figure out where.  Might I suggest Process Monitor and a lot of angst?  In the meantime.. wait your 15 minutes and call it good.. not worth a new PS if this is the only symptom.

Comment: I only restart when software requires it basically, and I boot up my machine once a day. It does bother me a lot but I can't seem to figure out if the issue is software. And 100% CPU on a single core on idle is concerning to me. I'm not familiar with Process Monitor, do you think it might pick up on something that Windows Performance Analyzer didn't? Also, there's no 15min wait. When it happens it will stay permanently until the machine gets turned off for a few hours and booted up again.

Comment: I am a Mac and Linux person, so cannot pinpoint with confidence but if you look at what you describe it seems like there is a background process that is being interrupted during reboot that then becomes high CPU when the system comes back on as it tries to “catch up” with whatever it was doing. For example, a system indexing process. That is actually a very high CPU task since physical files and such are being indexed into a database. Perhaps when a shutdown or sleep happens, the process cleanly pauses itself but for some reason on reboot it just abruptly stops. Thus high CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there something you can suggest me to do to see if that's the case? Do you not think it's related to a hardware issue?

Comment: @quantum400ideal I gave you the best advice I can give you. It is now your task to take that advice and use it in some way.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yeah that's what I was trying to do. But use it how?? In what way??It's the main reason I came here since I'm not a IT pro by trade. But your advice does not point me in any direction. I asked for clarification, not a condescending attitude.

Comment: If the problem is in the ACPI, a device might be hung, consuming all those CPU cycles during initialization. Are all your devices working correctly? Sata, M.2, PCI, USB controllers/ports. Try disabling them in BIOS one by one (when possible) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the latest Windows and Razer updates this morning the problem no longer persists.
I have done several restarts to be sure and PC is idling at 1% after restart on every instance. These were the updates I installed:

- Razer Inc - HIDClass - 6.2.9200.16511
- Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version: 1.349.651.0)
- Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 version 20H2 (KB5004331)